# package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation is not visible

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

When I compile my Spring Boot application in Java 9, it fails after a couple of messages such as this one:

```
package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation is not visible
    (package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation does not read it)
```

Can someone tell me what is going on here? As I understand it, any pre-Java 9 code not in a Java-9 module will be part of the unnamed module where anything is exposed.

I'm using this as an annotation like this in my module:

```
@JsonIgnore
public Week getNextWeek()
{
    Calendar instance = this.getFirstDay();
    instance.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, this.week + 1);
    return new Week(instance);
}
```

So if this is the case with the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation package, why is the error referring to a module with that name, and why is it a problem that it does not read it?

Comment: The error hints that you are compiling module com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation and the code in that module has a reference to a type in package com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation on the class path. Are you trying to compile com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation as an explicit module? Can you post the javac command that you are using?

Comment: I'm not explictely trying to compile it. I have edited my question to show how I'm using the module.

Comment: You're updated question makes it look like you are compiling a module but you've put the dependency on the class path rather than the module path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the [JigSaw Spec](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#the-unnamed-module):

> The unnamed module exports all of its packages. This enables flexible migration, as we shall see below. **It does not, however, mean that code in a named module can access types in the unnamed module.** A named module cannot, in fact, even declare a dependence upon the unnamed module.

What you're looking for are [Automatic Modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#automatic-modules). In automatic modules, a `jar` can be placed on the module path and will automatically derive the module name from the `jar` itself. In case you're using Maven, that should be the `artifactId`.

As such, if you are using `jackson-annotations` in maven as following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You'd still require to define it inside your `module-info.java`:

```
module example {
    requires jackson.annotations;
}
```

After that, you're free to use the annotations within your module.

Comment: Hey Jaims, I'm having this exception:

`Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private java.lang.String me.project.mosaicov2.login.LoginResponse.access_token accessible: module main does not "opens me.fullcam.mosaicov2.login" to module jackson.databind`

and i'm requiring jackson.annotations in my module-info. Tryied to "opens me.fullcam.mosaicov2.login to jackson.databind;" but it not compile...